# call my private constructor

Tags: winforms

Is there a way to call my private constructor from my public constructor?

```
public class MyClass
{


  public MyClass(string id)
  {
    //Want to call MyClass() constructor here somehow
  }

  private MyClass()
  {

  }

}
```

Comment: Let's assume I know nothing about how C# constructors work. First, I can do a search engine query for "C# constructor". I can click on one of the first links on the first page, which gives me [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ace5hbzh.aspx). On that page there's a link called ["Using Constructors (C# Programming Guide)"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173115.aspx). That page says that a "constructor can invoke another constructor in the same object by using the this keyword". You can use a similar process to research other topics on your own in the future.

Comment: Please, mark vc 74 as correct.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
public MyClass(string id) : this()
{
}
```